# Nested data and BLoCs in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

My Flutter app has the following general structure:

1. The initial screen shows a list of contact objects. The user can tap a contact, which brings up
2. a detail screen that lets the user see the whole contact info, and modify any details temporarily. The user can either
3. dismiss the screen without saving the changes, or
4. tap a save button, which updates the contact permanently, and upon completion leads back to the initial screen.

I'm using FireStore. The list is built with `Stream<QuerySnapshots>`, and when the user taps an item, the app's router parses the route name (e.g. `/contacts/123`), creates the respective `DocumentReference` and forwards it to the detail screen's initializer, which then uses `DocumentReference.get` to load the details, and `DocumentReference.updateData` to save changes. Works beautifully – but is only a proof of concept.

Now I would like to hide FireStore and the remaining business logic behind a BLoC. This leads to some questions:

1. Keeping business logic out of the UI, as far as I understand it, implies that I should stick to named routes, and have the detail screen somehow use the route details to retrieve the relevant contact data through the BLoC. Is that true, and what's the best solution for this?
2. How can I subscribe to nested data using the BLoC? I want the detail screen to observe data changes, so that I can warn the user if the data becomes stale. Using functions on BLoCs (something like `streamOfContact(contact) -> Stream<Contact>`) is forbidden, so how would I do that with Sinks? Or is there generally a different way to do this without breaking the BLoC pattern? I'm very new to all of this, so may very well be I'm overlooking something important.
3. Similar question: How would I update a particular contact?

The tutorials I've found online only deal with root data (e.g. adding cart items to a cart, handling user authentication, ...), but I haven't seen an example showcasing nested data yet. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: You do not need to handle this with the router, for example, you can simply map over the list of contacts and when I tap on one contact you will pass the respective value/details of the tapped contact (i.e: `ContactDetails(details:allContacts[uid])`) in this case allContacts would be a map of <String,Detail> and `ContactDetails` widget would be a dumb widget that only shows the contact details passed from the contact list

Comment: Thanks, that would work, but I would like the detail widget to update whenever the contact changes. Contacts are shared across multiple apps (and users), so they can change anytime. The reason I would prefer to use named routes is because then I can open contact details from any location in the app, not just from the overview list.

Comment: This is a bit too broad. While I understand your concerns, I cannot provide a finite answer. Can't you recenter your question on one specific point? You're free to ask other questions if needed

Comment: Hi did you find a way? If so, could you share some code? I’m also struggling with this pattern. Thank you.

Comment: I was able to solve all problems with the help of Bofomer's excellent answer below. If you have questions about specific details from in my post above, please elaborate – or even better, consider posting your own question and link it here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) Routing and navigation is in the responsibility of the UI layer. That means the UI layer must call `Navigator.push[Named](...)`.

If it makes sense, you can move the logic that decides if the app should navigate to the detail screen:

```
// in the BLoC:
Stream<int> showContactDetail;

// in the UI layer:
bloc.showContactDetail.listen(_showContactDetail);
```

How you transfer the parameters to the detail route is totally up to you. You can use named routes, but it would be easier to transfer data with a builder:

```
void _showContactDetail(int contactId) {
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return ContactDetailPage(
      contactId: contactId,
    );
  }));
}
```

---

2) One BLoC should be tied to a single screen, that means there should be a separate BLoC for the detail screen (or dialog/sidebar/...), and you would pass the id of your contact to the second BLoC as a constructor parameter, or using a `StreamSink`, or using a simple setter method.

I would recommend you to use plain old methods instead of `StreamSink`s for the BLoC inputs. [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/96nhta/brian_egan_build_a_reactive_flutter_app_droidcon/e43z21f/) is a recent discussion about the topic.

---

3) The question is not only how to update your contact from the detail screen, but also how the detail BLoC obtains the contact data (if you are only transferring the contact id).

The answer: Another application layer, what I would call the **data layer**, that is shared between all BLoCs. You can store the data in Firebase, a sqlite database or a simple `Map<int, Contact>`.

The data layer would also propagate changes to the backend, and notify all BLoCs when the data has changed, probably using a `Stream`.

---

The next question that would come up is where you put this data layer (e.g. a class called `ContactService`):

- You can create the `ContactService` in your `ContactListPage`, then pass it to the `ContactDetailPage` in a constructor parameter (using a route builder, as explained above). No magic here. A side effect that you may not want is that the service will be discarded when the list page is popped.
- `InheritedWidget` that is above the `MaterialApp`, or at least above the `Navigator` generated by the `MaterialApp` (You can use the `builder` of `MaterialApp` to wrap the navigator with your own widgets). Putting it that high up in the tree ensures that all pages of your app can access it.
- Using scoped_model, which is basically the same. Must also be inserted above the navigator to be accessible from both routes
- A static variable/singleton